# Unable to use a live usb.

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb, live-usb

Update to 64-bit 12.04LTS fails. I remade the LiveUSB once using Startup Disk Creator, and twice using unetbootin. I then, thinking it was the USB, used a different one using unetbootin. Also a failure. I have an HP 2000-2d69NR Notebook PC, 1.75GHz AMD E2-2000 CPU, 4GB RAM, AMD Radeon HD 7340 Discrete-Class graphics, 500GB HDD with Ubuntu 12.04LTS amd.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can't boot into the live CD, right?

In your bios, try to disable UEFI boot, and set it to Legacy mode. Disable safe booting, too. Also, make sure that USB is at the top of the boot list, I always forget that :)

If you mean that the update starts, but fails, you would need to provide provide more information on your problem, your question is a little unclear :(

Comment: Couldnt disable UEFI, all options were in uefi. somethingx4, somethingx6 and somethingx4+6, which is the one i was on. I set it to legacy mode and i did what it told me then it just booted back into the os, i couldnt find where to take off safe boot either. usb is at the top of the list but no avail. Also your understanding is correct.

Comment: scratch that, i was able to find secure boot and i disabled it. and IPv4<EUFI> IPv6<EUFI> and IPv4x6<EUFI>